# Is a low bridge the same as an underbridge / undercrossing / passage underground?

Tags: word-meaning

In an English class somebody claimed that. My research online lets me assume otherwise.

A low bridge seemed to me to be just that: a bridge not high enough for some trucks.

Do you agree? Thanks for answering!

Comment: To keep this question from being closed, you should describe exactly what traffic structure you are asking about, in case _none_ of these terms are known to some respondents.  For example - Are you asking about a spot where a road dips down to go underneath another road that stays level?  In the U.S., we would commonly call that an _underpass._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bridge is the joining structure between two high points, to carry some kind of traffic, road, rail etc.

The underbridge is what goes under that point, the overbridge it the one that goes over - it's all the same bridge, just defined from 2 standpoints.
If a railway goes above a road, then to a train it's an overbridge, to a car it's an underbridge.

An undercrossing is not a word I've heard, nor does a dictionary search give much help, though the meaning can easily be extrapolated.
It doesn't describe *what* may be crossing.

A passage underground could be anything from a drain to a tunnel, or even pedestrian underpass - walkway under a road.

None of these adequately conveys the same meaning as **Low Bridge**
…a meaning it is not wise to get wrong…

[image] [image]

Comment: Undercrossing is quite common here (western US), as a minor road, or even a path for cattle/wild animals, that goes under a freeway or other major highway.

Comment: I thought it might be a US term, but was surprised that a simple 'define [word]' on Google came up with a lot of misses…. but as a compound word it's pretty simple to figure out, so I let it go. I'd guess underpass would be the UK equivalent. Freeway's another one we'd never use here… but I know what one is, of course ;-)